# Heatmap with K Clusters and RowName Annotation

Tags: r, heatmap

I have a dataframe that looks like this with a gene name, a gene family and Log2Fold Changes . I am able to put the fold changes in a heatmap but would like to annotate the rows (on the right side of the heatmap) with only the gene families while also doing K-means clustering (making 5 clusters) on the entire heatmap. Is this possible in ComplexHeatmap? I have attached my dataframe:

```
tf.logs



    Name 0dpi 1dpi 7di 14dpi 22dpi
Gene1 MYB 1 2 3 4 5
Gene2 WRKY 4 3 6 5 11
Gene3 ERF 3 4 5 66 2
Gene4 bZIP 3 4 5 6 6
Gene5 EFR 4 4 4 4 4
```

My code for the heatmap is this:

```
heat.gen = Heatmap(tf.log, width = unit(4, "cm"), km = 6 
                   cluster_columns = F, 
                   show_row_names = F, 
                   row_gap = unit(1.25, "mm"),
                   row_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "sans", fontsize = 8, fontface = "bold"), 
                   name = "Log2FC", 
                   column_title = "Resistant - Susceptible", 
                   column_title_gp = gpar(fontfamily = "sans", fontsize = 16), 
                   col = colorRamp2(c(-4,0,4), colors = c("dodgerblue2", "cornsilk", "firebrick1")))
```

I also have a data frame with the gene names and the families:

```
 Family
Gene1 MYB 
Gene2 WRKY 
Gene3 ERF 
Gene4 bZIP 
Gene5 EFR
```

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about `ComplexHeatmap` but this is very easy with the [`pheatmap`](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/pheatmap/versions/1.0.12/topics/pheatmap) package. Simply provide the annotation dataframe as `annotation_row`. You can cluster both rows and columns.

I've used both packages and prefer `pheatmap` personally.